# ffmpeg add watermark out of memory

Tags: video, ffmpeg

we want to add watermark to video using ffmpeg. When the video is relatively large, there will be out of memory.  Below is our code, how can I go about eliminating this problem.
enter code here

```
        filter_args = '[1][0]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih*0.06[logo][video];[video][logo]overlay=0:(main_h-overlay_h)'
        cmd = [
            'ffmpeg',
            '-i', mp4_done_path,
            '-i', './watermark.png',
            '-filter_complex', filter_args,
            videoPath
        ]
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```